# jar file doesn't execute

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to execute jar file of netbeans swing small project.
The file isn't executing. 
I need to make it work by double clicking on the jar file that is located in:

```
C:\Users\armyTik\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Notepad\dist\Notepad.jar
```

**extra details:**

properties -> Build -> Packaging -> "Build JAR after compiling" and "Copy Dependent Libraries" are checked.

properties -> run -> Main class: "notepad.NotepadComponent"

In the cmd, by manually executing the jar file I get the following error:

```
cd C:\Users\armyTik\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Notepad\dist
java -jar Notepad.jar
"Error: Could not find or load main class notepad.Notepad"
```

What should I do, specifically?

---

**EDIT:**

I extracted the jar file and got:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
notepad/FileManager.class
notepad/icon.gif
notepad/NotepadComponent$1.class
notepad/NotepadComponent$2.class
notepad/NotepadComponent$3.class
notepad/NotepadComponent$4.class
notepad/NotepadComponent$5.class
notepad/NotepadComponent$6.class
notepad/NotepadComponent$7.class
notepad/NotepadComponent.class
notepad/Thumbs.db
```

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_102-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: notepad.NotepadComponent
```

Update2:

I got new exception while trying to open the jar from the cmd:

**While opening the project from netbeans, the icon is shown with no exception.
*****When I remove the icons , The jar is working! but I need to keep the icons in the application.**

[image]

Comment: what about `java -jar Notepad.jar notepad.NotepadComponent` ?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: what is the file structure of your src directory? It seems like the path you provided to your main class might be wrong?

Comment: It may also be possible that the tool you have used to build the `jar` is not configured correctly. Whats the content of the `jar`s `MANIFEST`-file?

Comment: @SamRedway src/notepad/ {3 classes and an image }. And I created the jar with "Clean and Build".

Comment: Learn about `Class.getResource` to retrieve resources relative to the class’ location/bundle…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your classpath is not correct.
Try it like this:

```
java -cp "<PATH>/Notepad.jar" notepad.Notepad
```

If this does not work then unpack the jar file and confirm the package and class name is correct, Print CLASSPATH env variable or check java and javac versions.

Comment: The cmd command you suggested gives the same error as befor. How do I "unpack the jar file and confirm the package and class name is correct Print CLASSPATH env variable or check java and javac versions" ?

Comment: rename to zip (windows) and unzip and confirm, 
java -version 
javac -version

Comment: I unziped. I got 2 folders: notepad / {(alot of java files).class} and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF   . What should I check here?

Comment: Main class java file entry will go into manifest file and your .class file should be in the directory similar to your package eg. notepad/Notepad.class

Comment: have you tried setting up classpath env variable? what is your java version (is it same from which you created the jar)? Add a screenshot of the Jar directory structure and Manifest file content.

Comment: Thanks for the big help. I updated the post with what you asked. I did not do anything by my self to update classpath env variable. Tell me if you need more details. thanks!

Comment: As per above updates your jar is getting executed. I dont see the class Notepad.class inside jar.Is it present? Check your code and see where is it referenced. cheers.

Comment: I dont have any class named: Notepad. I have 2 classes in my project: FileManager.java,NotepadComponent.java (swing gui) and an icon: icon.gif

Comment: obviously somewhere in your code this name is referred right? how is it printed in error "Error: Could not find or load main class notepad.Notepad" ?

Comment: My main class is not notepad.Notepad. it is : notepad.NotepadComponent as I mentions above. Can you look agian what I updated ?

Comment: You mention that Jar is not executing and also have a NPE exception, it is confusing. It seems your program is executing but have some exceptions.

Comment: See what is mentioned in line 58 of your class NotepadComponent